# Mathjax not rendering inline labels

Tags: javascript, d3.js, mathjax

I am trying to render inline mathjax labels [here](http://www.d3geometry.com/sine?g=x) along the x axis.

This is a react site and when the DOM is loaded, I have this code, I had to use setTimeout because MathJax is not available until I add the delay:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub,], d3.select('.x.axis')[0][0]);
}, 500);
```

I create the labels like this using this code:

```
const xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient('bottom')
        .tickValues(xTickValues)
        .tickFormat((x) => '$\pi$')
        .scale(xScaleAxis);
```

I'm just trying to render pi at this stage but even that is not working.  Mathjax is definitely doing something because when I view source, I see this on the tick value label:

```
<text dy=".71em" y="9" x="0" style="text-anchor: middle;"><span class="MathJax_Preview" style="color: inherit;"></span><span id="MathJax-Element-1-Frame" class="mjx-chtml MathJax_CHTML" tabindex="0" data-mathml="<math xmlns=&quot;http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML&quot;><mi>p</mi><mi>i</mi></math>" role="presentation" style="font-size: 116%; position: relative;"><span id="MJXc-Node-1" class="mjx-math" role="math" aria-hidden="true"><span id="MJXc-Node-2" class="mjx-mrow"><span id="MJXc-Node-3" class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.249em; padding-bottom: 0.496em;">p</span></span><span id="MJXc-Node-4" class="mjx-mi"><span class="mjx-char MJXc-TeX-math-I" style="padding-top: 0.434em; padding-bottom: 0.311em;">i</span></span></span></span><span class="MJX_Assistive_MathML" role="presentation"><math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mi>p</mi><mi>i</mi></math></span></span><script type="math/tex" id="MathJax-Element-1">pi</script></text>
```

But nothing is being displayed.

Comment: I don't see any "d3 is not defined" error in the console, yet, I can't find the d3 library defined in your HTML. Did you link the d3 library?

Comment: It is all done with webpack and d3 is not global.  I use npm to import d3

Comment: Looks like you are trying to append html `span` to svg `text`, perhaps swith to svg output: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/options/SVG.html

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm amazed at how difficult this is.  While `MathJax` has an [SVG renderer](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/config-files.html#the-tex-mml-am-svg-configuration-file), it embeds the resulting `svg` in html.  The hack I've come up with here, is to move it back into the tick after it's rendered.

```
setTimeout(() => {

  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });

  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
          svg.selectAll('.x>.tick').each(function(){
          var self = d3.select(this),
              g = self.select('text>span>svg');
          g.remove();
          self.append(function(){
            return g.node();
          });
        });
      }, 1);
    });

  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub,], d3.select('.x.axis').node());

}, 1);
```

Full code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>

  .axis {
    font: 10px sans-serif;
  }
  
  .axis path,
  .axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #000;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  }
  
</style>

<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjax/2.7.0/MathJax.js?config=TeX-MML-AM_SVG">
  </script>
  <script>
    var margin = {
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        bottom: 10,
        left: 10
      },
      width = 500 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 200 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
      .domain([1,5])
      .range([0, width]);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
      .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
      .scale(x)
      .orient("bottom")
      .tickFormat((x) => '$\\pi$')

   var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height/2 + ")")
      .call(xAxis);


setTimeout(() => {
  
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['$','$'], ["\\(","\\)"] ],
      processEscapes: true
    }
  });
  
  MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("End", function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
          svg.selectAll('.x>.tick').each(function(){
          var self = d3.select(this),
              g = self.select('text>span>svg');
          g.remove();
          self.append(function(){
            return g.node();
          });
        });
      }, 1);
    });
  
  MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub,], d3.select('.x.axis').node());
  
}, 1);
    
    
  </script>
```

**EDITS**

I've extended this example [on this block](http://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/86077bddc91c3de8d3db6a53216b2f47) where I use `MathJax` and `d3` to label the radians of a circle.

Comment: Note from the future: cdn.mathjax.org is nearing its end-of-life, check https://www.mathjax.org/cdn-shutting-down/ for migration tips.